# Does Ethereum 2.0 support 100K TPS per shard or totally?

Tags: transactions, ether

Hello recently i read that Ethereum 2.0 will handle 100K also i read that it will support 64 shards. Thus i think that the 100k TPS is an estimation for a total of 64 shards not 100k per shard because its seems unreasonable am i correct?

Comment: not ethereum 2.0 after the merg in September … he said at some point of the future after everything is implemented (years from now) it will reach 100k

Comment: @Majd TL yes but this 100K TPS will be from both 64 supported shards or not?

Comment: I don't think that shards will be used to process transactions. You will not get 64 tiny blockchains. I think they will just use them to improve data storage. But don't take that as an answer. I'm not very involved in the ethereum roadmap

Comment: @MixalisNavridis It's total. You may also be interested in participating in future [EF Research AMA](https://old.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/vrx9xe/ama_we_are_ef_research_pt_8_07_july_2022/if7ekua).